# Multiple checkbox selections to display in textbox

Tags: c#, .net

I'm new to this, please bare with...
I have 4 checkboxes, each displaying a $ amount depending on the selection.
I have it working so that if 1 checkbox is selected, textbox shows $1.00 or $20.00.
But, I'm having trouble with if 2 checkboxes are selected it would be $21.00 or 3 checkboxes or  all 4.

I have this to show one checkbox selection.

```
if (checkBox247Access.Checked)
{
    textBoxExtras.Text = "$1.00";
}
```

Comment: You could take the container all the four checkboxes are in and find the checkboxes with the `Children` collection. That gives you an array of checkboxes that you can iterate over (or use linq) to calculate the sum. Then assign this sum to the textbox.

Answer (score 1):

something like this should work, but as in comment above you might want to use particular container to iterate through i.e. iterate through groupbox instead of entire form just incase you have checkboxes in other container/groupboxes

```
foreach (Control ctrl in form1.Controls)
{
    if (ctrl is CheckBox)
    {
         //do the logic of if checkbox is checked
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do, is handle the `CheckedChanged` event for all 4 checkboxes. You can even use the same eventhandler for all 4.

Then, in the handler, add up alle the selected extra options, and add them to a variable. After figuring out the total amount, update the textbox.

Here's an example:

```
private void checkBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int amount = 0;

    if (checkBox247Access.Checked)
    {
        amount += 20;
    }

    if (checkBoxFreeCoffee.Checked)
    {
        amount += 1;
    }

    if (checkBoxExtraThing.Checked)
    {
        amount += 3;
    }

    if (checkBoxBonusThing.Checked)
    {
        amount += 11;
    }

    textBoxExtras.Text = "$" + amount.ToString("n2");
}
```